# React Native - Object.assign is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native, babeljs

I just installed the project `react-native-redux-router` from github and I'm trying to have it working.

Although, it looks like I have an issue somewhere as I get the following error.

I tried to reinstall everything I could, but nothing works.

I'm running the latest version of nvm (0.31.0), latest version of node (5.6.0), latest version of npm (3.7.3) and the latest version of react-native-cli (0.1.10) installed globally.

I searched on different forums how to fix the issue and I can't find a solution. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: While I haven't seen this exact error, I'm currently dealing with a similar error. In my case, I've recently upgraded from 0.14.2 > 0.20. I was able to get it working, but each time it was short lived and felt very fragile. I'm not ready to call it a bug yet, but something isn't right. Which version of RN are you using? Have you tried with a fresh project? That would be my recommendation.

Comment: The version used by the project is 0.17

Comment: If you're using the latest version of `react-native-redux-router` then it should be compatible with v0.17. You may want to double check. It looks like he updated the code 1 month ago, but hasn't updated the release number from 1.0.3 since Nov 2015. Also, FYI, he's no longer supporting it and recommends you use https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux instead.